# moment.js - Convert Zulu time

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I am using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) and trying to convert a Zulu time into MMMM D, YYYY

```
moment("2017-02-23T11:02:45.000Z", "yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss.SSS")
```

This is not working for me, does anybody have an example?

Comment: Your code works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/a8fwrjd5/. Check the console for errors and ensure you've included all required scripts

Comment: I get 'Invalid Date' when I run that fiddle

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use right case in format string:

`moment("2017-02-23T11:02:45.010Z", "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS")`

Answer (score 0):

From the docs

> There are upper and lower case variations on the same formats. The
>   lowercase version is intended to be the shortened version of its
>   uppercase counterpart.

However, in this context, the `dd` part of your code needs to be uppercased. The rest of the string is identical to yours.

```
// before 
// yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss.SSS

// after
// yyyy-MM-DDHH:mm:ss.SSS
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xqd5gpvs/1/